# I'm hitting runtime error 9 "Subscript out of range" with my code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a warehouse item manager, where I can add or remove items from warehouse amount.

I'm stuck on copying existing data range to my manager, which I'm doing with following VBA script. It should copy certain data range from workbook to another workbook, with user form.

I'm opening the workbook which I'm going to copy, via file path which I've already defined ("Tiedosto.Text."), this is from a textbox.

```
  Private Sub AddFromWorkbook_Click()

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim thiswb As Workbook
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long

  Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Tiedosto.Text)
```

Problem is this line: "`With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")`"

```
  With wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 
     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  MsgBox (LastRow)

  With thiswb.Sheets("Sheet4")
     j = .Cells(.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  End With

  For i = 2 To LastRow
     With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
         If .Cells(i, 13).Value = "X" Then
            .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=thiswb.Sheets("Sheet4").Range(3 & j)
            j = j + 1 'Kasvatetaan j.n arvoa sen edetessä.
        End If
     End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

So this should copy row by row from workbook to another.
But this just returns a runtime error 9, when I try to run it.

Comment: Does “Sheet1” definitely exist in the workbook you’ve opened?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, new sheet name depends on the language version of your MS Office. As a result, the new sheet's name is not always "Sheet1", it could be "List1" or so, depending on the language.

With this in mind, I suggest replacing line `wb.Sheets("Sheet1")` with `wb.Sheets(1)`, which is the first sheet of the workbook and which always exists.

Comment: I changed all sheet references ie. wb.sheets("sheet1") to wb.Sheets(1) and now I'm hitting different problem: runtime error 1004, with following line: .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=thiswb.Sheets(4).Range(3 & j)

Comment: I guess problem lies within `.Range(3 & j)`. For example, if j = 1, you get `.Range(31)` which does not exist. Range requires 2 parameters.

Comment: Changed .Range(3 & j) to .Range(3, j) no luck. still same error.

Comment: Does ***.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=thiswb.Sheets(4).Range(3 & j)*** exist? ( 
 Sheet(4) )

Comment: Change `.Range(3 & j)` to `.Rows(j)`  @Toni

Comment: Also if the workbook has only one worksheet then `wb.Sheets(1)` is safe to use else the `wb.Sheets(1)` *may* not be the sheet you think it is. Best is to open the workbook and double click on the sheet name to highlight it and copy the name from there. @Toni

Comment: I tried the .Rows(j) and it works, but not in the way I want. That just pastes the copy range to column 1, and I need it to go from column 3. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Toni: Then you cannot copy the row `.Rows(i).Copy`. and paste it into Col C. You need to do something like this `.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Copy` Where `A` and `D` are your start and end columns. And then you paste it at the 3rd column `Destination:=thiswb.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C" & j)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the suggestions to fix this problem. I changed the range like descriped and also the destination, but still ran into error code 1004 and error code 13. I deicded to just revert the code to when it worked, .Rows(j). I'll get back to this when I'm not in a hurry to finish this project. Thanks again for your time.